# Python, Finding the number of times each token appears in a given file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, counter

I want to list the tokens appearing in a file with the counts of that tokens. I wrote the below code but it isn't working as I like.

```
from collections import Counter
import re

seen = set()
words = re.findall(r'\w+', open('deneme.txt').read().lower())
seen = Counter(words).most_common()

print (seen)
```

And the deneme.txt is like this:

```
Erke Varol
Antalya Koleji 
123 123 
Erke
Erke 
 (asdfsdf)^'
Erke Varol
Antalya
123
Antalya
aç+Noun birak+Verb 
aç+Noun ol+Verb 
aç+Noun ol+Verb 
aç+Noun ol+Verb
```

The result is as follows with my code:

```
[('erke', 4), ('aç', 4), ('noun', 4), ('verb', 4), ('antalya', 3), ('123', 3), ('ol', 3), ('varol', 2), ('koleji', 1), ('asdfsdf', 1), ('birak', 1)]
```

My problem is I want to get aç+Noun or ol+Verb as a single token but with this code it is not possible and I didn't understand why.

Comment: Try `r'\w+(?:\+\w+)?'` in your `re.findall` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characters class `\w` includes only alphanumeric characters and underscore, so if you want `+` to be considered part of a word you should include it in a character set:

```
words = re.findall(r'[\w+]+', open('deneme.txt').read().lower())
```